# Does the sum converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I have used the limit comparsion test and done the following

[image: Solution]

So is the sum divergent or convergent? I think it diverges because $b_n=1/n$ which is a p-series with p=1. But my friend said it is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it diverges. Your argument is correct: since the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges too.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Really appreciate your help!